# Remove category number fill

Tags: categories, wp-admin

I need create menu but my category list is a 2 page.

I want remove this number and show all category in 1 page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override the default of per page, you can set the number to '' to instruct the query to return all categories. Add the following code to your functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'show_all_categories_admin_nav_menu', 10, 2);

    function show_all_categories_admin_nav_menu( $args, $taxonomies ) {
        if( reset($taxonomies) === 'category' ) {
            $args['number'] = '';
        }

        return $args;
    }
```

If you set the number to blank it will still shows the numbers of page even though it's showing all the categories.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you this code worker for wordpress category but not working for woocomerce category

Comment: plesae edit code for woocamerce product category

Comment: if( reset($taxonomies) === 'product_cat' ) edit this if condition

Comment: very very thank you . thank you .thank you.
iset number 200,1,200.
i want show all category.how number i must to use?

Comment: if this is help you please accept my answer

Comment: Its depend how much category is there

Comment: Can you please tick my answer as correct if my answer is satisfied you.